# how to break out of the loop if the boolean condition is false

Tags: bash, if-statement, command-line, terminal, while-loop

Hi guys the problem i am trying to solve is that the while loop will work in both cases even if you type no and the second problem  echo would you like to carry on if i type yes it will break out in both cases

```
echo would you like to provide  more numbers: 
read des

while [ "$des"=="yes" ];  do

    echo provide a number please:
    read num
    let x=3num+$num
    echo $x

    echo would you like to carry on 
    read new

    if [ "$new"=='no' ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

To complete your string comparison, add spaces:

Instead of

```
while [ "$des"=="yes" ];  do
```

write

```
while [ "$des" == "yes" ];  do
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

if [ "$new" == "no" ]; then

Comment: try with spaces around `==`

Comment: Spaces are absolutely required. `"$new" == "no"` is not an expression; they are 3 separate arguments to the `[` command, and as such, need to be separate by whitespace.